# Vue Chart JS re-render chart when data updates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm building a Nuxt JS front-end that contains Vue Chart JS & an API whereby it fetches data every X seconds and saves the data to the Nuxt JS store. However, after my chart has rendered, despite the data udating correctly, I can't seem to reliably re-render the chart.

I have a plugin, `LineChart.js` that includes my chart:

```js
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = true;

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  data () {
    return {
      localData: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.localData = this.chartData

    // this.chartData is created in the mixin.
    // If you want to pass options please create a local options object
    this.renderChart(this.localData)
  },
  watch: {
    chartData: {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        this.localData = val
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
}
```

I thought by adding a watcher on `chartData` I can at least find out when my data changes, and it does.

I've tried destroying and re-rendering the chart inside of my `handler` function, but this results in an infinite loop. `this.chartData` does update, I just need to re-render the chart.

Comment: Can you make sure val and oldVal are different? Otherwise i believe it will keep firing after the first time.

Comment: Shouldn't need a watcher. Does it work if you render chartData directly `this.renderChart(this.chartData)` ?